# php insertion not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

i tried to parse a xml and insert the content into a database. the code works with a string i put in, but not with the connected variable. is there a typo in my code? 
how can i do this

```
include 'example.php';//include xml here
$haus = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach ($haus->features as $features) { foreach ($features->properties as $properties) { 
    echo "<br />".$properties->name, ' is live ', $properties->website, PHP_EOL;
    $name = $properties->name;

    if ($insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO locations (name, website)
    VALUES ($name, 'page')
    ")){
    echo $mysqli->affected_rows;
    }

} }
```

what am i doint wrong here?

Comment: I hope you have it in one line "INSERT INTO locations (name, website)
VALUES ($name, 'page')"

Comment: @SubirKumarSao Why does that matter?

Comment: @BrendanBullen My bad its allowed in PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing single quotes around the value for `$name`:

```
INSERT INTO locations (name, website)
VALUES ('$name', 'page')
```

FYI, if you check for errors in your code you would have caught this quickly. You can use [`$mysqli->error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get the error message from MySQL.

Comment: shame on me. sorry too much coding today! :D